# Fastest way to Cat and Copy files in java

Tags: java, file, unix, runtime, nio

I'm searching for the fastest way to `cat` and `clear` files in java , the way which not use jvm to copy so the act of coping files be the fastest way,

i'm using `unix` command to do that:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandArray);
    int correct = process.waitFor();
    if (correct == 0) {
        System.out.println("file appended successfully");
    } else {
        System.out.println("problem to append file");
    }
}
```

so is it the fastest way ? or i should use `nio`?

Comment: Java NIO is recommended as you can run the code on any platform. Your code will fail to run on Windows OS since you're specifying Unix commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Java nio2 - platform independent